# Exception handling in Django of queryset

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I'm trying to catch an exception if a user does not exist and redirect if that's the case.

When I run this I get an error saying:

> 'NoneType' object is not iterable

```
try:
    return {'sub_user': User.objects.get(username=username)}
except User.DoesNotExist:
    redirect('home')
```

How can I catch this error? I tried with:

```
try:
    return {'sub_user': User.objects.get(username=username)}
except User is None:
    redirect('home')
```

But that gave me another error:

> catching classes that do not inherit from BaseException is not allowed

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not in how you catch the exception.

You need to return the result of the call to `redirect`.

Comment: What does this mean?